# How should I ask about how to handle a situation in a particular country when a question exists about that exact situation in another country?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Someone asked about how to deal with bus stops adjacent to cycling lanes in Germany: [Who goes first? Person disembarking bus or the bicycle?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141463/who-goes-first-person-disembarking-bus-or-the-bicycle), where the accepted answer explicitly refers to the German traffic regulations concerning this matter. I'd like to ask this question about Belgium because I sometimes encounter this situation myself and it is relevant to people traveling to Belgium. Chances are the answers won't meaningfully change due to the general geographic proximity of both countries, but who knows, the Belgian traffic regulations might be different, or the socially acceptable answer might be different. Wrongful assumptions in this could lead to dangerous outcomes. However, the only meaningful difference between the question I want to ask and the question that inspired me is that it's set in a different country, so it could end up getting closed without me getting the information I want because people might assume it's a duplicate (which it almost is, but not quite).

How should I deal with this situation? Should I just ask this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest asking the question with (a) Belgium prominently in the title and as a tag, (b) including a link to the German question to clarify it is not, in your eyes, a duplicate. As you state the traffic situation is different in different countries.